# kendo grid column sequence number

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to kendo UI for Asp.net MVC and I had a requirement to have sequence number in kendo Grid as 1,2,3,4 etc. Also in-case of 'Add new record' the sequence column should get the latest number and add 1 ( for example : If the records in the grid are 4 and has 1,2,3,4 as sequence it should have 5 in the new record).
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think one or both of these links would answer your question:

[How Can I Have Row Number In Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112330/how-can-i-have-row-number-in-kendo-ui-grid)

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
sortable: true,
dataSource: [{
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 30
}, {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 33
}],
columns: [{
    field: "name"
}, {
    field: "age"
}, {
    field: "rowNumber",
    title: "Row number",
    template: "<span class='row-number'></span>"
}],
dataBound: function () {
    var rows = this.items();
    $(rows).each(function () {
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        var rowLabel = $(this).find(".row-number");
        $(rowLabel).html(index);
    });
}});
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/row-number-in-kendo-grid

```
<script>
  var rowNumber = 0;
  function resetRowNumber(e) {
      rowNumber = 0;
  }
  function renderNumber(data) {
      return ++rowNumber;
  }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid()   
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Template(t => { }).Title("Row No").ClientTemplate(
            "#= renderNumber(data) #"
        );
    })
    .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("resetRowNumber"))
)
```

In summary, add an additional column for the row number with a template, you will also need to set a databound event that loops through the rows and grabs the index of the row (+1 if you don't want to include zero) and binds it to the template.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the gentle guidance, I don't answer often. Will try and edit it.

Comment: @JAL yes the person above you just pointed that out, and the answer was edited to reflect it.

Comment: @JAL no worries! I'm usually a lurker-- I didn't even know that the queue existed or wouldn't have bothered. Clearly, a learning moment for me. I had a couple of bookmarks from dealing with the same issue. The rule makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like below on data binding from this [reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Templates/add-row-numbers)

```
<script>

 var RecordNumber = 0;

 $("#grid").kendoGrid({  
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
              { title: "&nbsp;", template: "#= ++RecordNumber #", width: 30 },
             ..
             ],
    dataBinding: function() {       
              RecordNumber = (this.dataSource.page() - 1) * this.dataSource.pageSize();
        }

 });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo of this? I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this of top of my head. Don't know if its the best way or not, anyway, it seems to achieve what you want:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid(
{
  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        item: "Item 1"
      }, {
        item: "Item 2"
      },{
        item: "Item 3"
      }],
    schema: {
      parse: function(data) {
        var count = 0;

        return data.filter(function(i) {
          i.count = ++count;
          return true;
        });
      }
    }
  }),
  columns: [{
    field: "count",
    editable: false
  }, {
    field: "item",
    title: "Item name"
  }],
  toolbar: [{ name: "create"}],
  editable: {
    mode: "inline"
  },
  edit: function(e) {
    var nextid = 0;

    nextid = Number($(e.sender.element).find("tbody tr:last td:first").text()) + 1;

    $(e.container).find('[name="count"]').val(nextid);
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/erIju)**</kbd>. It basically set the number in the `parse()` event, which you can avoid if you can set the numbers on the server-side. Then it sums the counter and set it to the new line.