# Add static row numbering in Kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo grid and Typescript. I want each row to be numbered but this numbering should not be affected by client sorting. So no matter what the client does to sort and rearrange the order of items in other columns, the numbering should always in order.

[How Can I Have Row Number In Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112330/how-can-i-have-row-number-in-kendo-ui-grid)

I found a related question, but it's in jQuery and I've been unable to implement the solutions. I've been looking through the kendo api but I haven't found anything to indicate there is a built-in function that does this. This is along the lines of what I have so far.

```
this.grid = Common.UI.Grid.getDefaultOptions([
    {
        title: "Row",
        field: "RowNum",
        sortable: false,
        width: 30
    },
    {
        title: "Name",
        field: "NamePerson",
        sortable: true,
        width: 90
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your link has a solution including an Angular one. If you are talking about somehow getting the SQL ROW_NUMBER server side, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity). Still not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Are you paging your results? Etc.